# Css grid, row height dynamic

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout like this using CSS grid

[image]

```
#producerContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}


#producerContainer
    div
        .formGroup
            label.formLabel Producer Name
            input

        .formGroup
            label.formLabel Full Name
            input

    div
        .formGroup
            label.formLabel Producer About
            textarea

        .formGroup
            label.formLabel Producer Name
            input

    div
        .formGroup
            label.formLabel Artwork
            // picture

        .formGroup
            label.formLabel Cover (Optinal)
            // picture
```

But the rows' heights are now allowing me to have the children right below each other, and this is what I have:

[image]

Is there a way for me to achieve this layout using grid or should I adopt a different system?

Comment: it's seems a mix of grid and common elements ... here you have 3 column and inside you put elements and each one will take the needed height

Comment: With grid-auto-rows you can set the rows as you want.

Comment: @TemaniAfif exactly, but how can I have the row take just as much space as needed?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I've tried every property of it, not changing anything

Comment: align-items: start seems to have fixed the issue